# How to stop tmux from minimizing terminal working area when accessing server through PuTTY?

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, putty, tmux

- Login to Debian server with PuTTY. Right-click on windows, select full screen. Have a nice big working area.
- Type `tmux` and immediately the working area is reduced to a standard small terminal window. Tried `active key` + `z`, but that (maximizing working area) does not seem to be the purpose of command.
- Using tmux v1.9 on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the underlying problem.

By default on connection the terminal window was sizing to 80x24 (even though it showed text files in wider resolution the typing was limited). Using

```
stty rows 50 cols 132
```

resolved this and tmux automatically goes to the specified size.

Comment: I think it isn't the place where you need to adjusted it, check my updated answer. It should be managed in `PuTTY` instead of on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Run `tmux ls`, if there more than two sessions than you probably started `tmux` on the server from console where physical screen is smaller than yours, so `tmux` will reduce screen to the smallest screen size. Either kill session that was started directly on server or exit from `tmux` on the server's console.

`tmux` allowing access to many people to the same users account, so if one working on the server from console, you will see it in your remote `ssh` sessions, kinda like `teamviewer`, both can see what are you doing.

P.S.

Another case of this issue could be "incorrect" settings for particular session in `PuTTY`.

When you opened `PuTTY`, don't click on a session you want to run, but highlight it and press <kbd>Load</kbd> button, then on the left side in "category" treeview expand "Window" branch and change radio button in "When window resized" scope to "Change the number of rows and columns" then go back (highlight "Session" in treeview) to the "Session" and press button <kbd>Save</kbd> to save new settings for this particular session. After doing that remote window will automatically resize itself when you resizing or maximized PuTTY window.